# Calculate a field django and save it in the database

Tags: python, django

I am just starting with Django and web development , so please be nice with me. i am trying to build an app that generates a new number to reports created by our inspectors (our company is an inspection company). each inspector chooses the type of reports, the inspection date and the client and the app saves the data and creates a report number . the report number is generated depending on the type of the report and the date. for example if i have 3 reports of type "visual inspection" done in 2022, the new "visual inspection" report will have the number 4/2022.

here is the code I used to attempt this but unfortunately it is not working:

Views.py

```
from modulefinder import ReplacePackage
from django.shortcuts import render
from report.models import Report
from django.http  import HttpResponse
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from django.db import transaction

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import ReportSerializer

@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def Report_add_view(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
        queryset = Report.objects.select_related('type').all()
        serializer = ReportSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    elif   request.method =='POST':
        serializer = ReportSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
# Create your views here.
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    code = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
class ReportType(models.Model):
    report_type = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    report_code = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    report_rev = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.report_type

class Inspector(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Report (models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    inspection_date = models.DateField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    inspector = models.ForeignKey(Inspector,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ReportType,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    reportlink = models.TextField()
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from django.db.models import  F

class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta: 
        fields = ['number','type','inspection_date','inspector','client','reportlink','date_created']
        model = Report

    number = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='report_number')


    def report_number(self, report:Report):
        print(report.type_id)
        num1 = Report.objects.filter(type_id = report.type_id).all().aggregate(num=Count('id'))['num']+1
        year = str(report.inspection_date)[:4]
        print(year)
        print(num1)
        return str(num1) + "/"+ year


class InspectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','full_name']
        model = Inspector



class ReportTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        fields = ['report_type','report_code','report_rev']
        model = Report
```

[screenshot of api result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOelL.png)

[database screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZKwv.png)

Comment: First `type` is not a good choice as a name, because it is a reserved python keyword. And second in your model `Report` you redefine `type` (specify two fields with the same name).

Comment: Also, please state your problem. You're just introducing your solution. What is your issue? Do you get errors? Which ones (HTTP Code)? In this case, also add a full traceback of the error. Check out this [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-stack-overflow-as-someone-totally-new-to-prog) for more details.

Comment: well thanks for your replies, the problem is that the report number is not being saved in the database . no HTTP errors

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the DRF doc: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield
SerializerMethodField is a read_only field.

To achieve what you're trying to do, i would override the "create" method of the serializer. It takes a dict of validated_data as parameter (generate thanks to the is_valid call you're doing).
In this method, you should be able to set validated_data["number"] with your desired value (return the modified dict at the end of the "create" method).

I'm not sure, but i think you should remove "number" from your list of fields in the serializer since you're calculating it.